# How do you delete a performance counter

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I know how to delete a Performance Category; which then also deletes all of the counters inside that Category, but how do you delete a single Counter within a Category in C# (without hacking the registry)?

Comment: post the code that you use for deleting the category please, it will help us get a clue about your context

Comment: PerformanceCounter implements the IDisposable interface, does Dispose what you want?

Comment: @ linkerro he you go;

PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete("categoryName");

But unsure how this helps as I never use this command and don't want to.

Comment: @dowhilefor It may do but how does that help?

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read on Performance Counter Categories, you can't delete or add performance counters to a custom category after it is created.  You need to delete and recreate the category or create a new one.  There is some information regarding altering categories at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty9fywea%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).